# Interlacing two vectors

Tags: r, string, vector, concatenation

Suppose I have two vectors defined as follows:

```
a <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
b <- c("b1", "b2", "b3")
```

Now I want to end up with a string vector like this one:

```
c("a1","b1", "a2", "b2", "a3", "b3")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I would be surprised if it wasn't possible, but is that concatenation? Do you mean "a1b1", "a2b2", etc? This needs to be clarified.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if I could call it concatenation either. I am not looking for "a1b1" etc., I'm looking for "a1", "b1"

Comment: See http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector/combining-vectors (adjust matrix, row args as needed).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can `rbind` them, then coerce back to a vector.

```
a <- c("a1", "a2", "a3") 
b <- c("b1", "b2", "b3")
c(rbind(a,b))

# [1] "a1" "b1" "a2" "b2" "a3" "b3"
```

As @Moody_Mudskipper points out, `as.vector(rbind(a,b)))` is faster

For the case when the lengths are different, I found the following solution from Rolf Turner at this link: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Interleaving-elements-of-two-vectors-td795123.html

```
riffle <- function (a,b) { 
  n  <- min(length(a),length(b)) 
  p1 <- as.vector(rbind(a[1:n],b[1:n])) 
  p2 <- c(a[-(1:n)],b[-(1:n)]) 
  c(p1,p2) 
} 

riffle(1:3, letters[1:5])

# [1] "1" "a" "2" "b" "3" "c" "d" "e"
```

There is also `vctrs::vec_interleave()`

```r
a <- paste0("a", seq(1e6))
b <- paste0("b", seq(1e6))

bench::mark(
  rbind = as.vector(rbind(a,b)),
  vec_interleave = vctrs::vec_interleave(a, b),
  mm1 = c(matrix(c(a,b),ncol=length(a),,T)),
  mm2 = c(a,b)[rep(1:length(a),each=2)+c(0,length(a))],
  mm3 = c(mapply(c,a,b)),
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is disabled.
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 rbind              22ms   57.6ms     21.9     30.5MB    11.9 
#> 2 vec_interleave   33.6ms   35.1ms     13.1     22.9MB     3.75
#> 3 mm1              61.7ms   70.2ms     12.8     45.8MB     5.48
#> 4 mm2              68.8ms  103.7ms      9.98    64.8MB     8.32
#> 5 mm3             884.3ms  884.3ms      1.13      69MB     3.39
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Those also work:

```
c(matrix(c(a,b),ncol=3,,T))
c(a,b)[rep(1:length(a),each=2)+c(0,length(a))]
c(mapply(c,a,b))
# [1] "a1" "b1" "a2" "b2" "a3" "b3"
```

but Ryan's solution is faster:

```
a <- paste0("a",1:10000)
b <- paste0("b",1:10000)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ryan = c(rbind(a,b)),
  mm1 = c(matrix(c(a,b),ncol=length(a),,T)),
  mm2 = c(a,b)[rep(1:length(a),each=2)+c(0,length(a))],
  mm3 = c(mapply(c,a,b))
)

# Unit: microseconds
# expr    min      lq      mean median       uq     max neval
# ryan  172.9  192.10   218.366  200.7   222.00   643.5   100
#  mm1  258.5  288.10   308.359  300.6   316.05   685.6   100
#  mm2  749.9  772.05   787.783  780.9   795.70  1104.6   100
#  mm3 9203.0 9585.70 11491.192 9978.7 10209.80 35516.3   100
```

`as.vector` makes it yet a bit faster:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  ryan = c(rbind(a,b)),
  ryan2 = as.vector(rbind(a,b)))

# Unit: microseconds
#  expr   min     lq    mean median     uq   max neval
#  ryan 169.7 185.65 198.797  194.2 208.10 302.0   100
# ryan2 108.8 121.05 135.465  128.3 142.85 297.7   100
```