# Join two data frames by inserting columns of one data frame in between very columns of the second data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame df1 which looks like this

```
A_1 B_1 C_1

a1  e1  i1

b1  f1  l1

c1  g1  m1

d1  h1  n1
```

I have then another data frame df2 which looks like this

```
A_2 B_2 C_2

a2  e2  i2

b2  f2  l2

c2  g2  m2

d2  h2  n2
```

I would like to merge the two df and obtain something like this:

```
A_1  A_2  B_1  B_2  C_1   C_2

a1    a2  e1   e2    i1    i2

b1    b2  f1   f2    l1    l2

c1    c2  g1   g2    m1    m2

d1    d2  h1   h2    n1    n2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cbind` them together and then use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516915/interlacing-two-vectors/50516988#50516988) to select the columns in the order you want (interleave the colnames of the two data frames).

```
cbind(df1, df2)[c(rbind(names(df1), names(df2)))]

#   A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2
# 1  a1  a2  e1  e2  i1  i2
# 2  b1  b2  f1  f2  l1  l2
# 3  c1  c2  g1  g2  m1  m2
# 4  d1  d2  h1  h2  n1  n2
```

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  bind_cols(df2) %>%
  select(sort(current_vars()))
```

Output:

```
   A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2
1:  a1  a2  e1  e2  i1  i2
2:  b1  b2  f1  f2  l1  l2
3:  c1  c2  g1  g2  m1  m2
4:  d1  d2  h1  h2  n1  n2
```