# Add to every number in scalar/vector `1` and insert the result after that number

Tags: r

I have many numerical scalars/vectors, like:

```
a <- 1
b <- c(2,4)
c <- c(5,6,7)
d <- c(60, 556, 30, 4, 5556, 111232)
```

Now I need to add to every number in scalar/vector `1` and insert the result after that number. The solution should work with any numerical scalars and vectors. So result should look like:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(2,3,4,5)
c <- c(5,6,6,7,7,8)
d <- c(60, 61, 556, 557, 30, 31, 4, 5, 5556, 5557, 111232, 111233)
```

How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst <- list(
  a = 1,
  b = c(2,4),
  c = c(5,6,7),
  d = c(60, 556, 30, 4, 5556, 111232))

lapply(lst, function(x) as.vector(rbind(x, x + 1)))
# $`a`
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $b
# [1] 2 3 4 5
# 
# $c
# [1] 5 6 6 7 7 8
# 
# $d
#  [1]     60     61    556    557     30     31      4      5   5556   5557 111232 111233
```

This is pretty much a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516915/interlacing-two-vectors/50516988), but not exactly so I'll let someone else make the call.

Comment: I tried to modified your code in order to process one scalar/vector at one time and get result as vector (that I need): `b = c(2,4)` 
`apply(b, function(x) rbind(x, x + 1))` . But that gives me error. How can I modify it to work?

Comment: You can run as `as.vector(rbind(b, b + 1))`

Comment: This `b = c(2,4)` 
`apply(b, function(x) as.vector(rbind(b, b + 1)))` gives me error : `Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Same with `b = c(2,4)` `
apply(b, function(b) as.vector(rbind(b, b + 1)))`

Comment: Just `as.vector(rbind(b, b + 1))`. It is already vectorized, no need for apply.

Comment: Or an option with tidyverse `enframe(lst) %>% group_by(name) %>%  summarise(value = list(c(rbind(value[[1]], value[[1]] +1))))  %>% deframe`